# Handle elements that have changing ids all the time through Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, dynamic, automation, detect

I am running the script to automate test cases and having this unique problem.
I have detected and used IDs of the elements for click etc. purpose. However, all of a sudden these ids have changed and the script works no more.
Another weird thing is those IDs are same as in script when inspected in Chrome but different in Firefox driver browser.

Firebug for test driver: -

```
<p class="description" onclick="selectElementTextListForIE(this,'tile29', 'tile19');selectElementTextList(this,'tile29', '')" id="tile29_span_0_0">
                                                            Platinum
                                                        </p>
```

Chrome inspector for same element: -

```
<p class="description" onclick="selectElementTextListForIE(this,'tile20', 'tile19');selectElementTextList(this,'tile20', '')" id="tile20_span_0_0">
                                                            Platinum
                                                        </p>
```

Also, what could be the best strategy for detecting such elements whose IDs are generated on run.
I even tried using XPATH but that too contains id's reference 
eg. @id="tile276_input

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Abhishek

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd show an example of HTML from Chrome and Firefox so that we can see the differences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can utilize CSS for this.  For your element, looks like its:

```
<* id="tile276_input" />
```

What you need to do is find out what is changing about it.  I assume it's the number inbetween. If it is, then your selector would look something like:

```
By.cssSelector("*[id^='tile'][id$='input']")
```

This will look for anything that has an ID that "starts with `tile`" and "ends with `input`.  In our case, `"tile276_input"` matches that.

See [this article](http://ddavison.github.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html) if you want more information

Comment: But there are multiple entries that start with same IDs.
Example: - 

browser.find_element(:id =>'tile20_span_0_0').click   #Platinum


browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 1

browser.find_element(:id =>'tile210').click    #Ok button

browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 1


#SELECT SERVICES

browser.find_element(:id =>'tile45_span_3_0').click #Thermographic

Comment: then you need to be more specific with your selector.  learn how parent-child-descendant hierarchies work with CSS and you'll solve your issue

Comment: @user007 - If you use Xpath , you can do complex selectors that involve getting an element then getting its parent, then getting a different child... etc.  You don't need to get by id. You can get elements by relative position with css or with xpath.

Answer (score 2):

You also can try `contains` and `starts-with()` for such things

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'title')]"))
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* [start-with(@id,'title')]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element = driver.getElement(By.cssSelector("[id^='title']);
```

Or

```
WebElement element = driver.getElement(By.cssSelector("id:contains('title')"));
```

You Can use this element to do desired actions.