# Click doesn't work on locate dynamic element which is in table

Tags: python, selenium

Use this way **self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[text() = 'image 2']/following-sibling::td/input")** I can locate this input element，but when I want to click it, it doesn't work.

```
<div class="animationImage">
  <table class="animationTab">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td class="deign_tab">Image List</td>
      <td class="deign_tab" style="padding-left:30px;text-align:center;">Select</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>image 2</td>
     <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="d6dea005-1b58-4890-8ea6-d561b30ba8c8" checked="checked">
     </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? You should include your attempts in the question, please read the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The flow content is my attempts. but it doesn't work.                                 #self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@class='animationTab']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input").click()
            #self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("table.animationTab>tbody>tr[2]>td[2]>input").click()

Comment: If you have `find_element_by_css_selector` why not `find_element_by_css_selector ('#d6dea005-1b58-4890-8ea6-d561b30ba8c8')`?

Comment: The id is dynamic. it can change.@fodma1

Comment: I'm not sure about the css syntax that can be used for Selenium, but the brackets don't work for sure. Try the following selector:`table.animationTab>tbody>tr:nth-child(2)>td:nth-child(2)>input`

Comment: I think the CSS selector is not the nicest solution, and it is very easy to break it. Is there any fixed part of the id? Selenium works with partial matches see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767834/2419215

Comment: All you method I have tried, but also doesn't work.-fodma1

Answer (score 0):

you can simply locate checkbox element with input tag like this,
//input[@id='d6dea005-1b58-4890-8ea6-d561b30ba8c8']

or if you have to access it with reference to table, then 
//table[@class='animationTab']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input

Comment: I have used the method you mentioned. but it doesn't work. The id is dynamic.  @Parry