# How to find a element with specific text in <span> with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm using Selenium WebDriver. I'm facing issue with dynamically changing ID. I've gone through some post such as [Handle elements that have changing ids all the time through Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767739/handle-elements-that-have-changing-ids-all-the-time-through-selenium-webdriver?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but didn't found a solution that can help me.

Including `start-with` and `contains`in XPath can't help as there are plenty of elements which start with similar text and id keep changing. Please refer the `HTML` below for more clarity.

```
<mat-option _ngcontent-c1="" class="__mat-option mat-option ng-star-inserted" 
     role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-4" 
     aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
   <span class="mat-option-text">
        <i _ngcontent-c1="" class="material-icons">description</i>
        <span _ngcontent-c1="" style="padding-left: 8px">Campaign Details</span>
   </span>
  <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
</mat-option>
```

- Notice the ID in the HTML above which is dynamic and keeps changing.
- There are few more elements like this which have the same class name.
- There are few more elements which start with `mat-option-`.
- The only unique this is the text in `<span>`.

I tried `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Campaign Details']"));` but not working for me.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Please clarify you want this element `<span _ngcontent-c1="" style="padding-left: 8px">Campaign Details</span>` or its ancestor: `<mat-option>`

Comment: Yes, want to find `Campaign Details` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided to identify the element with text as **Campaign Details** as the element is an *Angular* element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visible* as follows:

```
WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//mat-option[@class='__mat-option mat-option ng-star-inserted' and @role='option'][starts-with(@id,'mat-option-')]/span[@class='mat-option-text']//span[contains(.,'Campaign Details')]")));
```

Comment: Be careful about this :  By.id("//mat-option[@class='__mat-option mat-option ng-star-inserted' and @role='option'][starts-with(@id,'mat-option-')]/span[@class='mat-option-text']//span[contains(.,'Campaign Details')]"  , id can't have //span and all the things you have written. Change it to xpath.

Comment: Similar to the question above, is there a way to find element with below HTML `<h4 _ngcontent-c8="" class="text-green" maxcounter="" style="margin-top: 3px;"> RM 10,000 &nbsp; <br _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8-13"> <sup _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-tns-c8-13" style="color: darkgray; font-weight: bold;">* excluding GST</sup> </h4>`. I want to find the RM 10,000. This amount is dynamic.

Comment: @cruisepandey any suggestions for me?

Comment: @Sanchit : Please ask a separate question.

Comment: Would'nt it be a duplication. Someone will surely downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The only unique this is the text in `<span>` So the text is : **Campaign Details**

```
WebElement campaignDeatils =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[text()='description']/following-sibling::span[text()='Campaign Details']"))  
campaignDeatils.getText(); // or any other operation you wanna do.
```

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey I already tried this but was not working for me. :-(

Comment: @ApoorvaSoni : try with this :  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[text()='description']/following-sibling::span[text()='Campaign Details']"));

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement campaignDeatils =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(""//i[@class='fa fa-bullhorn']/following-sibling::span[text()='Campaigns']"))  

campaignDeatils.getText();
```