# I cant seem to be able to type in to the input box

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, input, text

I'm trying to enter content into an input box on the following website using selenium.

```
https://www.telia.no/kundeservice/kontakt-oss/kontaktskjema/
```

I'm using this Xpath to address the input box:

```
//*[@id="c4548208-26f1-4f89-aa7e-ceef0f60de81"]
```

I have tried to use xpath, classname, id and also `time.sleep` but I still get his error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
    {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="96509b70-d1d6-4bbb-82ef-516e80cebc56"]"}
```

How do I type into the textbox?

Comment: please add your full code

Comment: also, you need to better specify which textbox you want, just looking at he page you linked I don't see any textbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle elements that have changing ids all the time through Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767739/handle-elements-that-have-changing-ids-all-the-time-through-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: You should post a pic of the input field that you want us to check, i can't find the id of the WE you're asking for..

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your question and the error message you showed indicate two *different* id's, supposedly for the same element. So it could be that the website is generating a new id each time the page is downloaded, which would explain why your code can never find it.

You could try to reach the element using attributes other than the id, or by going through its parents.

Answer (score -1):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.telia.no/kundeservice/kontakt-oss/kontaktskjema/")
# click accept cookies
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cookie-consent-form-container"]/div/div/div/button[1]').click()

#click search icon
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/div/div/button/div").click()

#input box
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/label/div/input").send_keys("abcd\n")
```